# What will happen when I git add and commit while git rebase branch

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

While rebase branch using command

```
$ git pull --rebase upstream devel
$ git reset HEAD
$ git status
```

**It shows output as mentioned in following image:**

[unstaged files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXEUq.png)

So, is it fine if I use **$ git add .** and  **git commit -m  "Message"** ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. try it and tell me what u got

Comment: please visit this URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXEUq.png

Comment: can you do a `git stash`?

Comment: You should not be able to perform a rebase while another rebase is in progress. Git should show you an error message instead.